# How do I access these dynamically created controls from the code behind?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a web page that starts off blank. With every button press new textboxes are added with a delete button to remove whatever row they want. That works great. The problem is I cannot access the dynamically created controls using C#.

In the code below I have them set up as `<input` I've also tried using `<asp:Textbox` but it also did not work. `Request.Form["txtItemName1"]` always returns a blank string and I cannot do `txtItemName1.Text` in the CS file because the textboxes don't exist yet.

How am I suppose to access the textboxes from the C# side?

Is there a better way to create controls dynamically?

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var counter = 1;
            $(document).on('click', '.removeButtonByID', function () {
                var _name = this.name.replace("btnRemove", "");
                if (confirm('Are you sure you want to remove line ' + _name + '? This cannot be undone.')) {
                    $("#TextBoxDiv" + _name).remove();
                }
            });

            $("#addButton").click(function () {
                $('<div />', { 'id': 'TextBoxDiv' + counter }).html(
                  $('<label />').html('')
                )
                    .append($('<div class="col-sm-1" style="width: 200px; padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 0px;"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Name" runat="server">').attr({ 'id': 'txtItemName' + counter, 'name': 'txtItemName' + counter }))
                    .append($('<div class="col-sm-1" style="width: 100px; padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 0px;"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="D/I" runat="server">').attr({ 'id': 'txtDI' + counter, 'name': 'txtDI' + counter }))

                    .append($('<div class="col-sm-1"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="">Subtotal</label>').attr({ 'id': 'subtotal' + counter, 'name': 'chkSubTotal' + counter }))
                    .append($('<br />'))

                .append($('<button type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>').attr({ 'name': 'btnRemove' + counter, 'class': 'btn btn-danger removeButtonByID' }))

                .appendTo('#TextBoxesGroup')

                counter++;
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- HTML -->

<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
   <!-- Dynamically added textboxes here -->
</div>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id='addButton'>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: when you tried using asp:Textbox, did you also include runat="server"?

Comment: Are you using C#  in ASP.net MVC or just ASP.Net?

Comment: Yes I did. I even manually put an asp:Textbox on the page just to see if I could access it and I could. Just the dynamic controls are eluding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# backend will not have access to dynamically jquery-created input fields. You can create server controls in ASP.Net with the code behind and using an [UpdatePanel as in the example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx).

Comment: There could be a point where this page will have over 100 textboxes - which I guess would I would have to create 100 update panels. Is this the most efficient way? Sorry - web programming is kind of new to me.

Comment: No, one update panel with 100's of dynamically created controls would work ok.